# Android View.GONE option and overall app speed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view

My app is really really laggy.Because i'm using many views&layouts with it.
If you want to see what i'm talking about check DO Launcher app from playstore. :)
I'm developing a launcher and that has a RSS feed & Twitter Stream on left page.
But lags happens when page changes to left page.
I'm thinking about to use (View.gone) when user changed the page.
And is that makes any difference ? i want to block lags.Maybe View.gone can solve the lag problem.So lags never will be happen again when View gone.

Or View.gone just hides the view,and keeps all other stuff on background ui and makes device laggy.

I mean does View.gone increase the speed overall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View.GONE will only hide the view and make sure it is not rendered nor occupies any space in the Layout. Think of it as CSS visibility:hidden vs display:none. It will not actually stop the object from being processed, only from being drawn on the layout pass.